# Spreadsheet for binary calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I have to design some fomulars that operate with integer numbers only. Further the some masks have to been applied to the numbers. The most often required operation is calculating the next number the can be divided by 4 without a remainder than is less or equal to another numnber. e.g.

```
1    FFFC 0
2    FFFC 0
3    FFFC 0
4    FFFC 4
5    FFFC 4
...
1022 FFFC 1020
1023 FFFC 1020
1024 FFFC 1024
```

I want to build a table with number patterns and check that the results match the requirements. Since the large number of cases I would prefer a spreadsheet like Excel. But I don't find a way to enter formulars that operate at bit level. Another topic is that the numbers should be entered and displayed as hex numbers.

- How can I make this binary (or bit level) operations with Excel 2003?

**Edit:**
There should be operations like

```
C1=BinaryAND(A1;B1)
```

where the result should be similar to the C expression

```
c = a & b;
```

i.e. The operation should be bit-by-bit.

Comment: please post an example table you need, what "check that the results match the requirements" means for you? "should be entered and displayed as hex" - it's not a problem in Excel, you can easily convert numbers between DEC and HEX with `DEC2HEX` and  `HEX2DEC` functions. "operate at bit level" - you can do the same also with decimal numbers (e.g. `ROUNDUP(<your value>/4,0)*4`).

Comment: Any comment about reason for downvoting?

Answer (score 1):

Citing..

> "calculating the next number the can be divided by 4 without a remainder than is less or equal to another number"

seems link a `MOD()` function to me..

For this one..

> "to enter formulars that operate at bit level"

tried : BITAND() BITXOR() BITRSHIFT() BITOR() ?

hope it helps.. (: